# Extremely long serve request times for mobile devices

Tags: apache

We've been noticing some extremely long (upwards of 2-3 minutes) time it takes to serve requests from apache in it's logs. Specifically for mobile devices.

I'm pretty light on apache knowledge, so what does this log parameter mean:

> The time taken to serve the request, in seconds.

Are these times long because mobile clients on flaky networks take a long time to receive their data? I would've thought apache dumped the data on the wire and wrote the log immediately?

If that is the case, then is there a reason why mobile networks would typically cause apache processes to take super long (keep alive, or something of that nature)? Or should I start looking internally toward my own code to figure out what's making apache take so long (again, I believe these endpoints to be relatively fine - e.g. fast).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read through some of the results for [this query on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=The%20time%20taken%20to%20serve%20the%20request%2C%20in%20seconds.). Basically it looks like, yes, it's the mobile device taking a long time to receive the data over a slow connection. It can't "dump the data on to the wire", the wire is not a big queue/waiting area. More packets are sent as the previous ones are received. You might augment your logging with some client-side data to learn more (render time etc and more details about the device and its behaviour).

Comment: Here I was playing around with terminology to find a good google search that got me what I wanted, when all I needed to do was be verbose :0 thanks!